# How to use mojang api to get uuids in python?

Tags: python, api, minecraft

I am pretty good at python and couldn't figure out how to use the Mojang API with python.
I want to d something like  `GET https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/<username>?at=<timestamp>`(from the API) but I can't figure out how to do it! Does anyone know how to do this? I'm in python 3.8.

https://wiki.vg/Mojang_API#Username_-.3E_UUID_at_time

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straightforward, just replace `<username>` with the person's username, and the response will give your their `uuid`.

Here is an example using **[`requests`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/)**:

```
import requests
username = 'KrisJelbring'
url = f'https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/{username}?'
response = requests.get(url)
uuid = response.json()['id']

print(uuid) #7125ba8b1c864508b92bb5c042ccfe2b
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. The only thing is, if I leave it as {username} I get an error. If I replace it with the name in the URL it works. If I set ```username = input("Enter The Username /n")``` how would I make it so it actually sets the username variable in the URL?

Comment: @Cloud my bad, I left out the `f` in my answer.   Try it now

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the documentation [here](https://wiki.vg/Mojang_API)
If you read the first few lines you will notice that there is a rate limit of 600 requests per 10 minutes. After that rate limit is reached you will raise a `KeyError`. To fix this we will use a try exception.

Don't forget to install the `requests` library.

```
pip3 install requests
```

Getting the user's `uuid`

```
import requests

user = "Notch"

try:
  resp = requests.get(f"https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/{user}")
  uuid = resp.json()["id"]

  print(uuid)

except KeyError:
  resp = requests.get(f"https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/{user}")
  error = resp.json()["error"]

  print(error)
```

**Timestamps**

If you want to check when a user's username at a certain time period, use a UNIX time.

```
import requests

user = "Notch"
ts = 1420088400  # Must be a UNIX value.

try:
  resp = requests.get(f"https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/{user}?at={ts}")
  uuid = resp.json()["id"]

  print(uuid)

except KeyError:
  resp = requests.get(f"https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/{user}?at={ts}")
  error = resp.json()["error"]

  print(error)
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is relatively straightforward.

You want to send a `GET` request with their username:

```py
import requests

username = "Bob"

resp = requests.get(f"https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/{username}")
uuid = resp.json()["id"]

print(f"Bob's current UUID is {uuid}")
```

Optionally, you can include a UNIX timestamp to get the username's UUID at a specific point in time:

```py
username = "Alice"
# UNIX timestamp that equates to 01/01/2018
timestamp = 1514764800

resp = requests.get(f"https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/{username}?at={timestamp}")

uuid = resp.json()["id"]

print(f"Alice's UUID on 01/01/2018 was {uuid}")
```

### Other Solution (third party library)

Alternatively, you can use my newly released [Mojang package](https://github.com/summer/mojang), if you don't want to deal with the HTTP requests, JSON, and other web junk in your code.

Install it with pip by running the following console command:

```
python -m pip install mojang
```

Usage:

```py
from mojang import API

api = API()

uuid = api.get_uuid("Alice")
print(f"Alice's UUID is {uuid}")

# or with a timestamp
uuid = api.get_uuid("Alice", timestamp=1514764800)
print(f"Alice's UUID on 01/01/2018 was {uuid}")
```